# How can I use .net CompilerServices.CallSite to compile a dynamic Expression Tree?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I'm trying to save a dynamic expression tree to a dll:

```
Expression<Func<dynamic,T>>
```

Here's what I tried so far :

```
  private static void SaveLambda(LambdaExpression lambda)
        {
            var asm = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("test"),AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);
            var type = asm.DefineDynamicModule("myModule", "test.dll").DefineType("myType");
            var method = type.DefineMethod("Foo", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static);
            lambda.CompileToMethod(method);
            type.CreateType();
            asm.Save("test.dll");
        }
```

This code fails with the following exception :

> System.NotSupportedException: Dynamic expressions are not supported by CompileToMethod. Instead, create an expression tree that uses System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite.

I've found various source suggesting CompileToMethod should work, albeit only for static methods, but it seems it doesn't if the method signature contains a dynamic...

I've tried to dig into [CompilerServices.CallSite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callsite_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) but haven't managed to find anything helpful...

Any idea?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? What are you using dynamic for?

Comment: I've written a mapper which transforms a dynamic object (typically a DapperRow) into a type (T). The end result is faster than native code and I'm trying to understand why, but I can't use ILSpy unless I save the compiled expression into a dll. It seems to me this is completely outside of the scope of this question, though ...

Comment: Probably your code is of the format `result.X = source.X; result.Y = source.Y; ...`. That works well because the DLR runtime-generates code for each of those dynamic accesses. The code is specialized to the runtime type of the objects involved. That's why it's fast. Should be slower than hand-written code, though.; By saving the expression to a DLL you will not be able to look at what the CLR generates at runtime. This is an XY-Problem.

Comment: It's not an XY problem. I think there are some legitimate use cases for what I'm trying to do, there's no helpful content anywhere on the Internet (try to google the exception and you'll see!), and I think it would make sense to have an answer to this problem on SO.

Comment: do you have dynamic used in your expression tree ? (you called Expression.Dynamic somewhere inside your lambda)